# How to stop Excel from updating worksheets copied from other files

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file, containing some sheet with some formula. I copied one sheet to another file and kept it on the same computer.

Now, if I change any formula or value in the master sheet, the copied sheet is also changed. I don't want this – so how can I disable that?

Answer (score 1):

When you copied the sheet it kept the reference to the other sheet in the formulas like this;

> =SUM([Budget.xls]Annual!C10:C25)

The `[Budget.xls]Annual!` refers to another file and sheet. You will need to remove these references to leave only the formula `=SUM(C10:C25)`

You can use *Find and Replace* to remove them.

**Note: Backup your work. Use at your own risk. Not responsible for lost data.**

1. On the Edit menu, click Replace.
2. In the `Find what` box, type refrence to the other sheet, `[Budget.xls]Annual!`, and leave the `Look in` box empty.
3. In `Options` choose to `Look in` formulas.
4. Click Replace All.